# How can i format SHA256 hash to bytes32 using ethers.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I created a solidity function with bytes32 array

```
function addHashes(bytes32[] memory _hashes){

}
```

to store SHA256 strings into ethereum blockchain. initially, I used `string[]` in place of `bytes32[]` since string[] is an experimental feature. so I changed it to `bytes32[]`.

to create sha256 hashes i am using `crypto-js` nodejs library.

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Message");
​
hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
> "2f77668a9dfbf8d5848b9eeb4a7145ca94c6ed9236e4a773f6dcafa5132b2f91";
```

and to connect with blockchain and interact with deployed contract i am using ethers.js.

When i convert this hash to byte32. i am getting below error

```
> ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("2f77668a9dfbf8d5848b9eeb4a7145ca94c6ed9236e4a773f6dcafa5132b2f91")
Uncaught Error: bytes32 string must be less than 32 bytes
at Object.formatBytes32String (/home/node_modules/ethers/utils/utf8.js:164:15)
```

I know the error says the hash should be 32 length string. But SHA-256  is 256-bit (32-byte)

Comment: Have you tried to prepend it with `0x`?

Comment: BTW, `CryptoJS.SHA256` already gives you an appropriate `bytes32` value, all you need is to convert it to a string (which you seem to have done already, via `hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)`), and then send it to your contract function. So why use `ethers.utils.formatBytes32String` to begin with?

Comment: Which one of them?

Comment: adding `0x` in start of sha256 fixes my issue